# Microsoft Teams: Finding trusted domains outside of Organization

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I am trying to get the list of external domains that have federation in place with the Microsoft Teams instance of my organization. We presently have an open Federation. I could not find a central place to get a list of external domains if open federation was configured. How can I obtain the list of external domains not the contacts that have a established federation with my organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the possible Teams federation information with the `MicrosoftTeams` powershell module. Here's an example:

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
Get-CsTenantFederationConfiguration

# output
Identity                            : Global
AllowedDomains                      : Domain=domain1.com,Domain=domain2.com,Domain=domain3.onmicrosoft.com
BlockedDomains                      : {}
AllowFederatedUsers                 : True
AllowPublicUsers                    : True
AllowTeamsConsumer                  : True
AllowTeamsConsumerInbound           : True
TreatDiscoveredPartnersAsUnverified : False
SharedSipAddressSpace               : False
```

Notes:

- Teams is Open Federation by default, with an empty `AllowedDomains` list
- Once you add domains to the `AllowedDomains` list, then your users are **only** allowed to send/receive to those. Not "open" anymore
- If `AllowFederatedUsers` is set to False, then it will **override** the `AllowedDomains`
- A description of the other settings can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/set-cstenantfederationconfiguration

---

You **cannot** see these settings for other tenants/domains

EDIT: Some other options that may be useful for finding what domains your users currently interact with:

- the list of 365 [Guest Users](https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home#/GuestUsers):
- Teams [Activity report](https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home?source=applauncher#/reportsUsage/TeamsUserActivityV1), and filter by unlicensed users:
- Do a Teams [eDiscovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-for-content-in-core-ediscovery?view=o365-worldwide) search, and export all the contacts

eDiscovery is the only real way to include everything, but it can be a lengthy process to get anything useful

Comment: "Teams is Open Federation by default, with an empty AllowedDomains list" - You are right, I see only an empty list and that's why I am trying to get the details of all the domains that have federation so that I can manually add them to the "AllowedDomains" List so that it becomes selective.

Comment: @Jack You cannot see the federation settings for other domains (unless you log into them). I'll add some other options to my answer